# Unbalanced multicolumn environment + wrapping footer results in footer moving

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, multicol, geometry

When using an unbalanced multicolumn (`multicols*` environment) and my footer has a `parbox` with text that wraps, the footer moves upwards. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can have it not happen?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=22.18mm,top=12.7mm,right=22.18mm,bottom=13.02mm,headsep=4.0mm,headheight=10.70mm,footskip=6.63mm,includeheadfoot=true]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[R]{\parbox[t]{0.4\textwidth}{\raggedleft Long footer text that wraps around to the next line}}

\begin{document}

\section{Footer Normal}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\section{Footer Moved Up}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\newpage

\section{Footer Back to Normal}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

In my real document, I have dynamic left and right footers and on occasion they are long enough to run into each other, hence the `parbox` solution to force wrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch. Looks like this is a bug that got introduced with patch pr4395 a while back. The issue is that when assembling the text columns, boxes got constructed and reconstructed and for that we need a `\boxmaxdepth` equal to `\maxdepth` as used during normal page generation.

However, when the final page is constructed (in the normal case) that \boxmaxdepth is unrestricted ie `\maxdimen`. As a result putting the columns and the footer together used the full height of `\footskip`.

Now with multicols setting `\boxmaxdepth` locally to `\maxdepth` that distance got shortend :-( . Why? Because the footer was defined as "top" box, i.e., one with a normal height and large depth. But with `\boxmaxdepth` restricted that is not possible so the depth is shortend and the height is increased. Now the `\footskip` separation is actually an unusually large baselineskip, so if the height of the footer box is large the baselineskip gets smaller and thus the separation. Tricky.

One can argue for both approaches, they are neither right or wrong. The issue is only that the standard OR does it one way and one branch of multicols did it the other way.

For the moment try this after loading multicols first:

```
% bug introduced with patch 4395?

 \usepackage{etoolbox}

 \makeatletter
 \patchcmd\multi@column@out{\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\partial@page\page@sofar}}
     {\boxmaxdepth\maxdimen
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\partial@page\page@sofar}}
   {\typeout{Success!!}}{\typeout{Patch failed!!}}
\makeatother
```

I will put a new version of multicols on CTAN (probably version 1.8p) after which that that patch is no longer necessary (though it will not hurt either).

### Edit

The new version of the package should by now be on CTAN.

Comment: Seems a duplicate question asked by me in texhax http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2016-March/022262.html but the new multicol works well. Thanks!

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA yes it is ... but I haven't come across your question as I don't monitor texhax these days.